# How to get complete parent directories tree via SVN Path Based Authorization

Tags: svn

I have following folders in SVN repository **marketing**:

```
/marketing/event1/pictures
/marketing/event2/pictures
...
/marketing/eventn/pictures
```

I have authorization configurations:

```
[groups]
head = user1, user2
visuals = user3, user4
[/]
* =
[marketing:/]
@head = rw
[marketing:/marketing/event1/pictures]
@visuals = rw
[marketing:/marketing/event2/pictures]
@visuals = rw
...
```

It is working in case the visuals group to checkout all pictures folders one by one. It is annoying if the sub folders become more.

The ideal solution is to let visuals group checking out /marketing/ once, get all sub folders tree excluding the files that visuals group has no right to read from. But there is authorization mistake while visuals checkout the /marketing/ from SVN.

Answer (score 0):

**Really** "Ideal Solution" (tm) will be

1. Read about SVN extenals
2. Build a) additional b) self-maintained tree of "Data for Visuals"

because your solution is possible even now, but expect (will **require**) something like

```
[/]
* =
[marketing:/]
@head = rw
@visuals = r
[marketing:/file1]
@visuals =
[marketing:/file2]
@visuals =
[marketing:/file3]
@visuals =
...
```

for **each and every file** inside "restricted" tree, whereas the use of externals will produce "one added line in property per added folder"

Comment: <pre>
[marketing:/]
@visuals = r
</pre>
is not working for me since the visuals should not read other files/folders from / except the picture folder.

to maintain tree is not convenient either since visuals group still need to checkout every folder one by one.

Comment: @HansChen - you are wrong both times. Re-read my text **carefully and fully** and read about Path-Based Authorization in SVN Book more times. Long follow-up in answer will appear later

Comment: I have tried svn:externals (assume that is what you mean). 
it works partially. I still need to add each restricted folder to main repository svn:externals like Events/2017/Euro/Pictures svn+ssh://svn@127.0.0.1/visuals/Events/2017/Euro/Pictures